# fontFamily Material Icons is not a system font and has to be Loaded through Exponent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, exponent, expo

I am importing Icon from react-native-vector icons with code:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
```

It seems like it is connected correctly. 
The code I am using to get an icon is :

```
 <Tab              
     title={selectedTab === 'home' ? 'HOME' : 'Home'}
     renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} name='android' size={33} />}
     onPress={() => this.changeTab('home')}>
     <Text>Home</Text>
 </Tab>
```

The full error i am getting is :

fontFamily 'Material Icons' is not a system font and has not been loaded through Exponent.Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Exponent.Font.loadAsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have changed your `.babelrc`, you need to use `babel-preset-expo` for react-native-vector-icons to work with Expo. See this example project I put together for you, where all I did was initialize it with `create-react-native-app` and then add the code that you provided for the icon: https://github.com/brentvatne/StackOverflow44811677

Your `.babelrc` should look like this: https://github.com/brentvatne/StackOverflow44811677/blob/master/.babelrc

You can read this thread for more information if you'd like to understand why this is happening: https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/12

Comment: That was nice of you to create an example project. I added the line ["babel-preset-expo"] to my presets and now everything works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The icons are actually fonts and must first be loaded.  It seems they are autoloaded sometimes and others times are not.

So to ensure they are loaded, do this:

```
        import FontAwesome from './node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf';
        import MaterialIcons from './node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf';
    ... 
      async componentWillMount() {
        try {
          await Font.loadAsync({
            FontAwesome,
            MaterialIcons
          });

          this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error loading icon fonts', error);
        }
      }
...
  render() {

    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {

      return <AppLoading />;

    }
```

See complete answer here:
http://javascriptrambling.blogspot.com/2018/03/expo-icon-fonts-with-react-native-and.html